# Getting AD Group Membership Count

Tags: c#, .net, active-directory

I'm looking for a native C# equivalent to PowerShell's ability to quickly retrieve a count of AD group members:

```
$users = Get-ADGroupMember -Identity 'Group Name'
$users.count
```

Every reference I've found for C# involves iterating through the group members and adding them to a secondary list that you can then access the "count" property of. I'd like to know the count of group members *before* I take action on it for my purposes, so this isn't ideal. I'm also trying to avoid running the "Get-ADGroupMember" PowerShell cmdlet in C# to I don't have to wait for a PowerShell instance to spin up.

Comment: Powershell is the way I usually do it.  Q: How often will you be making this query?  What's really the difference between 2 seconds and ten seconds, anyway?  Perhaps the [Microsoft Graph API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/azure/ad/graph/howto/azure-ad-graph-api-operations-overview) might also be of interest to you.,

Comment: You say you don't want to read the members into a list and access the Count property, but that's exactly what you do in your PowerShell example. Please explain in your question in more detail why you don't want to or cant do this.

Answer (score 4):

Regardless of whether you do it in C# or PowerShell, you have to enumerate the members to get a count. The count isn't stored.

However, `Get-ADGroupMember` is slow because it's creating a new [`ADPrincipal`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.activedirectory.management.adprincipal?view=activedirectory-management-10.0) object for each member, which, in turn, looks up the attributes for that object - that's one more network request for every member. You don't need that if all you want is a count.

The `member` attribute of a group is just a list of strings: the `distinguishedName` of each member. All you need to do is count those, without actually looking up those accounts.

You can do that with [`Get-ADGroup`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/addsadministration/get-adgroup?view=win10-ps), and just ask for the `member` attribute. Then get the count.

```
(Get-ADGroup "Group Name" -Properties member).member.Count
```

Now, things get more complicated if you want to look through nested groups: if a member of the group is another group, do you want to look inside? If so, that'll slow things down.

If you do want to go down the road of C#, I wrote an article about how find all the members of a group, depending on how your AD environment is setup and the nature of the groups you're looking at: [Find all the members of a group](https://www.gabescode.com/active-directory/2018/11/30/find-all-members-of-group.html). However, in many cases I did look up the member accounts to get details of it. So you'll need to modify it likely. But I'm happy to help if you need it.

Comment: Very good observation - that didn't occur to me!  Another option the OP could pursue - if he really insists on C# - is WMI: But ADSI is definitely better than WMI, and PS is arguably "better" than either.